# gsub a special chracter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hy 
i try to use gsub  for remove this character ’  be carful it's not ' or ` he come from  Word(microsoft) i think .
i really dont understand why i cant remove this character because i can remove all others

when i use gsub like that :

```
pattern = /(\’|\"|\.|\*|\/|\-|\\|\)|\$|\+|\(|\^|\?|\!|\~|\`)/
restring = string.gsub(pattern){|match|" " }
```

i get this error below

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
   pattern = /(\’|\"|\.|\*|\/|\-|\\|\)|\$|\+|\(|\^|\?|\!|\~|\`)/

              ^
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your RegEx through Rubular's site, I got this;

[image]

I figured it was a UTF-8 issue and after some additional stack overflow, it seems pretty common in a rails app to add `# encoding: utf-8` to the top of your file.

Comment: i try that  syno = info.text.force_encoding("utf8")                                       p = syno.gsub(pattern){|match|" " }

Answer (score 0):

You might add the following to your regex:

```
/\u2018|\u2019|\u201A/
```

which are some curly single quotes: `["‘", "’", "‚"]`.

In case you're interested, here is a simple method I've used before for cleaning up Word text (pieced together from a number of resources online):

```
def replace(text)
  text.
    gsub(/[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]/, "\'").
    gsub(/[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]/, "\"").
    gsub(/\u2026/, "...").
    gsub(/[\u2013|\u2014]/, "-").
    gsub(/\u02C6/, "^").
    gsub(/\u2039/, "<").
    gsub(/\u203A/, ">").
    gsub(/[\u02DC|\u00A0]/, " ")
end
```